# .htaccess and regex puzzle

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the URL below by removing strings both before and after the string that I want to keep. I need to do this efficiently, as I have 30,000 URLs like this to redirect.

I know I can use a regex rule to remove the strings before the string I want - `blah-blah-blah-the-post-title`  - but I don't know how to remove the remaining `&catid=210:the-category-title&Itemid=7891011`. And I need to add a trailing slash.

**So, in other words, I need redirect this URL pattern**

> `http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123456:blah-blah-blah-the-post-title&catid=210:the-category-title&Itemid=7891011`

**to this pattern**

> `http://www.domain.com/blah-blah-blah-the-post-title/`

*Is it possible to do this in .htaccess with grep? Or am I better off using php?*

And, if php, how? (Both regex and php novice here).

Comment: I would honestly use PHP for it, but if you're set on using htaccess, then it's definitely possible, but just very complex.

Comment: When you enter `http://www.domain.com/blah-blah-blah-the-post-title/`  in a browser does it load the page properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for. We're parsing the server variable query string `%{QUERY_STRING}` for the `GET` variable `id`. We don't want the first part of the variable, so we're not going to capture it inside of our RegEx group `()`; the part in the parenthesis should be what you're looking for. Also we're going to try and end it before any other variable in the query string by looking for anything that is not an `&` character. Then we look for a possible literal `&` character.

We use the `%1` to echo the captured string in our rule, then we append the slash and add a `?` mark to show that we do not what the behavior of `[QSA] Query String Append`. We're telling it we want a redirect, so we pass it `R` and `L` for last. If you want it to be a permanent redirect you can use `[R=301]`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} id=\d+:([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule .* %1/? [R,L]
```

`.htaccess` is better (quicker), but to do this in PHP you would want to edit the code that creates this link first. However, if you're trying to change this link on the page once the page loads you can do this (at the top of the page):

```
if(preg_match('!^/index\.php!',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
   if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $parts = explode(':',$id);
       $newPath = 'Location: /'.$parts[1].'/';
       header($newPath);
       exit();   
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the .htaccess rule.

Comment: That works great! If need be, I can also set my Wordpress permalinks to year/month/ and your rule redirects from my long URL to /blah-blah-blah-the-post-title/ and then WP redirects to /2013/8/blah-blah-blah-the-post-title/

Answer (score 0):

Update: Using .htaccess I'm not sure you are able to access parameters. Nor do I think it's necessary? If you want to display a different page to the user, then you should look at the code below.

If you use PHP then this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

in your .htaccess will make:

```
http://www.domain.com/blah-blah-page/
```

into something like:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?url=blah-blah-page
```

QSA basically means it keeps the given parameters, e.g.:

```
http://www.domain.com/blah-blah-page/?test=hej
```

becomes:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?url=blah-blah-page&test=hej
```

Then in your PHP you would do something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    unset($_GET['url']);
    $v = explode('/', $url);

    $lowerCaseAction = strtolower($v[0]);
}
```

Hope this will help you on the right track.

Comment: `RewriteRule` declarations don't see query strings. You would have to capture it with a `RewriteCond` statement.

Comment: I have a feeling that the entered url is the actual http://www.domain.com/blah-blah-page and not the one with parameters. However, I can be wrong. Though in either case the first bit is incorrect.